# html data not being displayed in MIMEtext python

Tags: python, html, email

i want to display this tick in cell in an html table in an email. Email is sent using Python.

[image]

Code is

```
<td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
```

This is how I am reading it in Python

```
html = open(filename)
emailMsg = MIMEText(html.read(),"html")
```

filename is the html data

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
      <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
      <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
      <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#x2714</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

In the email this is how the ticks appear

[image]

I know the html code works, because i can retrieve the same html data via browser which shows the ticks

[image]

Comment: The entity should be terminated with a semi-colon: `&#x2714;`

Comment: @snakecharmerb - That didn't make a difference given that it works in a browser.

Comment: Then the problem is probably with whatever is rendering the email.  Perhaps it's using a font that doesn't support the tick character?